# FosUserBundle - How to go back to specific page after login and go back on main page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 3.1.

I start that my my title isn't clearly correct.

I'm using Fosuserbundle to login to the "backend" of my application.

I have my main page with tab "administration". I click on it and then i log in to my backend. Than i have a link with redirection to my main page.

Now when i click again in "administration" i see again login page, but in right corner i have information that i'm logged ( well it's true).

I don't want to login again to aplication. In that moment i want to see on my screen page which i see after first time i log in.

How to tell my aplication that i'm still loged in and i dont't need to log in again??

Security.yml

```
 providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /Group

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Please share your `security.yml` file

Comment: I edited post and added security.yml